# Supabase Nuxt 3 Redirecting to Login on Login

Tags: nuxt.js, supabase

I've got Supabase `'@nuxtjs/supabase'` running, it was working fine until I moved some layout's around and now I just cannot get it to redirect to a `/confirm` page on successful login. Any help would be great.

`layout/default.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="dark bg-gray-800 min-h-screen w-screen h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <NuxtPage />
    </div>
</template>
```

`login.vue`

```
<template>
  <Auth />
</template>
  
<script setup>
    definePageMeta({
      layout: "page",
    });

    const user = useSupabaseUser()

    console.log(user.value)
  
    const linkDestination = ref(user.value ? '/generate' : '/login');
</script>
```

Then my `nuxt.config`

```
  supabase: {
    redirectOptions: {
      login: '/login',
      callback: '/confirm',
      exclude: []
    }
  },
```

On login with either magic link or OAuth provider, just redirects me back to the `/login` page and `user.value` is `null`

Am I doing something plain wrong here?

Comment: Is your re-routing logic running on the client side or the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You could use inside your defineNuxtConfig outside of the app:{} if you have it:

supabase: {
redirect: false,
},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).